# Shell Script - get field/column of csv that contains value pass by array

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sh

Shell Script - get field/column of csv that contains value pass by array

sample data of inputdata1.txt file has value like -

```
id name gender
```

sample data of test.csv having multiple field/column some of has value id with value like
2 row of test.csv

```
/"id":"21"/, /"p1":"abc"/,  /"id":"22"/  
/"id":"23"/, /"p2":"zyx"/,  /"id":"24"/,  /"id":"25"/
```

similar has multiple row

Require output - get those column only has contains like id & I can get whole row but I want that column only

output like of below format 2 row of csv

```
/"id":"21"/ /"id":"22"/
/"id":"23"/ /"id":"24"/ /"id":"25"/
```

Facing issue "${keywords[$j]}" does not return any value if I used for print only It's work with this command having issue

```
awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~ "${keywords[$j]}") {print $i}}' test.csv
```

my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a keywords=(`cat inputdata1.txt`)

length=${#keywords[@]}

for (( j=0; j<length; j++ ));
do
awk -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~ "${keywords[$j]}") {print $i}}' test.csv
#awk -F, '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~ "id") {print $i}}' test.csv

printf "Current index %d with value %s\n" $j "${keywords[$j]}"

done
```

Require output - get those column only has contains like id & I can get whole row but I want that column only

1. If I try to remove ' from command the it give me error - :

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: line 14: `  awk -F, {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~ "${keywords[$j]}") {print $i}} request.csv'
```

2. If I try to add " then error is

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
    {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if >>>  (~ <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

Comment: I don't recommend `awk` for parsing CSV files, as it can't (easily) handle quoted fields. Use a language that has an existing CSV library.

Comment: @ASHOKDAUKIYA 1) Your working awk will not produce the same output as you gave where it has multiple results in one line. 2) Because you iterate through the same file multiple times and you compare with a regex, your output can have repeated instances, is that what you wanted? 3) Can't tell if `inputdata1.txt` is separated by spaces or lines or both. Where is the example?

Comment: @konsolebox if I use passing hardcoded value like id then it's work as require but not work with array - awk -F, '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~ "id") {print $i}}' test.csv

Comment: @ASHOKDAUKIYA Yes with one result per line. Your example output shows multiple results per line.

Comment: @ASHOKDAUKIYA Please look at the inconsistencies I mentioned and clarify what you want or how you want things done.

Comment: @konsolebox this will works shows multiple results per line

Comment: @konsolebox test.csv data - abc /a1 \"dpi\":480 \"dt\":1 \"ID\":\"22\" \"ID\":\"12\"
abc /a1 \"dpi\":480 \"dt\":1 \"ID\":\"23\" \"ID\":\"13\" I getting below

Comment: @konsolebox output is "\""ID\"":\""22\"""
"\""ID\"":\""12\"""
"\""ID\"":\""23\"""
"\""ID\"":\""13\"""
"\""ID\"":\""22\"""
"\""ID\"":\""12\"""
"\""ID\"":\""23\"""
"\""ID\"":\""13\"""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU awk for arrays of arrays and sorted_in:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
{ gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"") }
NR==FNR {
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        tag = $i
        gsub(/^\/"|".*$/,"",tag)
        vals[tag][NR] = (NR in vals[tag] ? vals[tag][NR] " " : "") $i
    }
    next
}
{
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        tag = $i
        if ( tag in vals ) {
            for ( rowNr in vals[tag] ) {
                print vals[tag][rowNr]
            }
        }
    }
}
' FS=', *' test.csv FS=' ' inputdata1.txt
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
/"id":"21"/ /"id":"22"/
/"id":"23"/ /"id":"24"/ /"id":"25"/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v var="${keywords[$j]}" -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ var) {print $i}}' test.csv
```

got answer thanks you all for your support !!

Comment: That's very fragile. Don't do that.

Comment: Again will show one result per line. Look at your example output. 2; 3 results per line.